# Having empty string from returning in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

When I use some characters like `/` in the textbox I get returned an `empty string` in `response`. I can easily make a check for `empty string` in my html but my question is how can I avoid having that empty string from being sent over in my `php` code?

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    if(!newVal==""){
         $.ajax({
              type : 'get',
              dataType: 'html',
              url : '/searchpost/' + newVal , 
              success : function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
              }
         });
    }
});

public function searchpost() {

        $q = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if(!$q) die();

        $string = trim(strip_tags($q));
        $db_string = urldecode($string);

        $this->db->select("postID, post_title, post_url, post_status");
        $this->db->like("post_title", $db_string);
        $this->db->or_like("post_url", $db_string);

        $posts = $this->db->get('posts', 10);

        if(!count($posts->result())) {
            die('Nothing to display');
        }

        ?>

        <ul>
        <?php 
        foreach($posts->result() as $m) : 
            if($m->post_status != 'active' OR empty($m->post_title)) continue;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo '/posts/'.$m->postID.'/'.url_title($m->post_title); ?>" class="url-post-title" style="font-size:14px;"><?php echo $m->post_url; ?></a>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <?php 

    }
```

Comment: / is used as an escape character, use console log and var_dump to check what you're sending and recieving.

Comment: @Aschab console printing out "(an empty string)"

Comment: console.log($(this).val()) gives you empty string?

Comment: @Aschab nope... the response. The input value is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your js function and use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the value before sending the request:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    if(newVal !== undefined && newVal.length > 0){
         $.ajax({
              type : 'get',
              dataType: 'html',
              url : '/searchpost/' + encodeURIComponent(newVal) , 
              success : function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
              }
         });
    }
})
```

Then you may have to handle the now url encoded value in your php function.

So instead of:

```
$db_string = urldecode($string);
```

Use [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

```
$db_string = rawurldecode($string);
```